# Noun for a person, out of a group of many, who did not give their approval for something

Tags: single-word-requests

I have information that serves as evidence of my company's illegal activities.  I share that information with 10 others in my department.  One of them goes to the press. That person is *the* **whistleblower**.

I have a form that I've filled out that needs approval before being submitted from 4 different bureaucrats.  3 give the form their rubber stamps of approval, but one does not.  That person is *the* ***blank***.?

Bonus: Is there a generic term for "a person who [...]"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109390/discussion-on-question-by-plast1k-noun-for-a-person-out-of-a-group-of-many-who).

Answer (score 1):

The person could be wilfully withholding their signature, or they could simply be on vacation and unaware that a signature is required.

In either case, and even with respect to things rather than people, a general term for this is [**bottleneck**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottleneck).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *noun*
> **2 a** : someone or something that retards or halts free movement and progress
>
> *transitive verb*
> : to slow or halt by causing a bottleneck
>
> // All decisions must be approved by the committee, and this is where the company runs into *bottlenecks*.

So:

> That person is the *bottleneck*.

---

The words can actually be used in a much greater number of situations than just that of somebody refusing to give a signature (or simply not having given a signature).

Some other possible contexts:

> "Charlie, why don't I have your proposal on my desk? What's the bottleneck?"
> "Donna, you know I'm waiting for everybody to agree to this deal. Who's the bottleneck?"
> "Those guys are just a bunch of lazy bottlenecks."

Answer (score 0):

"spoilsport" comes to my mind as the word. This means someone who spoils the group objective by not joining in an activity. This word would be appropriate if that person's refusal is frivolous. If it has a good reason (that person may well be entitled to their opinion validly), then using this word may not be appropriate.

Other less polite words could be "killjoy" or "party pooper"

You could use "nonconformist" or "lone dissenter", but I suggest delving deeper into their meaning and usage.

Answer (score 0):

To express an opinion different from others is by definition to [**dissent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissent).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> 1: to withhold assent or approval
>
> 2: to differ in opinion
>
> Three of the justices **dissented** from the majority opinion.

Though dissenting carries risks, the term itself is neutral.

Catching an issue and speaking up about it is dissenting from a general opinion. A **dissenter** might not give approval for something the group is keen on. For example, "That Pat is the dissenter."

*Innovative pioneer*? *Stinker, spoilsport, or bottleneck*? All in the eyes of the beholder.

Bureaucracies do not readily welcome differing from the pack. Despite perennial lip service to thinking creatively ("outside the box"), the herd mentality often looks unfavorably on new ideas. Therefore, dissenting comes with inherent risk. Could be brave to be the dissenter, could be missing social cues.

Answer (score 0):

When the person is specifically withholding agreement / approval, that person is a “holdout”.